# Cakephp User management plugin implementation

Tags: cakephp

I had downloaded the plugin from link
https://github.com/CakeDC/users

followed the steps given in the page. I have created the tables 'users' and 'details'. I have also registered the user and verfied the user, but while accessing the link www.mydomain/users/users/login this page is getting redirected to www.mydomain/users/login
which shows missing controller. I am new to cake and for me it is difficult to debug. I would be thank if some one help me.

---

Thank you for the response.

Yes, I have added the code given in the "cake\libs\controller\app_controller.php" file. In order to test this I have freshly downloaded the core files and setup the files in my local system. I have placed the plugins 'utils', 'search' and 'users' to my app/plugins folder and created the tables.

Now also I am able to register the user but not able to see the login page. ie. "while accessing the link www.mydomain/users/users/login this page is getting redirected to www.mydomain/users/login which shows missing controller".

Please let me know if I am missing anything or I am wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem in the login redirection.

Did you add the beforeFilter() configuration to your app_controller?

if not you may need to add it.

Here is an example of how your app_controller should look like:

```
<?php
    class AppController extends Controller {
        var $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Auth');

        function beforeFilter(){
            $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd');
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
            $this->Auth->authError = __('Sorry, but you need to login to access this location.', true);
            $this->Auth->loginError = __('Invalid e-mail / password combination.  Please try again', true);
            $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
            $this->Auth->userModel = 'Users.User';
            $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
        }
    }

?>
```

Remember that the $this->Auth->loginAction MOST contain the 'plugin'=>'users', without it it will go to www.mydomain/users/login instead of www.mydomain/users/users/login

Comment: I tried to edit your post and correct the beforFilter() -> should be beforeFilter(), but StackOverflow believes my edit should have minimum of 6 chars (?).